# Dynamically allocating an int array

Tags: c

```
int funkcija(int broj)

{

    int *niz;
    int i;

    *niz = (int*)malloc(broj*sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < broj; i++)
    {
        niz[i] = rand() % 50;
        printf("%d\n", niz[i]);
    }

    return *niz;

}
```

I need to make a function which takes a number, dynamically allocates a string/sequence of numbers, initializes it with random numbers and returns it. Any assistance?

Comment: Remove the `*`s before `niz` and put a `*` before `funkcija`. `niz` is a pointer to `int`, and `*niz` is an `int` and it is actually the same as `niz[0]`. If you write `int funkcija(...` then you return an `int` but you want to return an pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code, for example, `malloc()` returns a pointer, so you want to assign a pointer to a variable which *is* a pointer. In other words, you should assign the return value of `malloc()` to `niz` and not `*niz`.

Next, `funkcija()` should return a pointer to where the array of `int`s with the random values reside. The return type should be `int *`.

In continuation with the above logic, your function should return the pointer `niz`. If you dereference `niz` (with `*niz`), you are returning the first element of the array (which is *not* what you need).

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
int funkcija(int broj)    
{    
    int *niz;
    int i;

    niz = (int*)malloc(broj*sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < broj; i++)
    {
        niz[i] = rand() % 50;
        printf("%d\n", niz[i]);
    }

    return niz;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void funkcija(int broj)
{

    char *niz;
    int i;

    niz = (char*)malloc(broj*sizeof(char));
    fillstring(niz, broj);

    //Use string here

    free(niz);
}

void fillstring(char *buffer, int len)

{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        buff[i] = '0' + rand() % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it make sense to put a call to srand inside a function called "fillstring"? Sounds like a function you might want to call more than once.

Comment: It is better to allocate memory in the same place where you will be free it. I don't like to call malloc() and return the pointer on allocated memory in the calling function.

Comment: Agreed with that (though in this case the function just leaks memory), but the srand call will have to be in some kind of init function, since it should only be called once.

Comment: @Beka the OP want's an the `funkcija` function return a pointer to an int array and not a to char array. And in your answer you return zéro, to the whole function is pointless. -1 until you improve your answer.

Comment: @Lundin. You are right, srand() call is initialization. I left srand in the fillstring function just to be sure the initialization is performed. It could be removed if calling side or main program call srand() by itself.

Comment: @Michael Walz. OP "... need to make a function which takes a number, dynamically allocates a string/sequence of numbers..." so I've changed the code a bit :)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.